# React, how to show sticky nav when scrolling

Tags: reactjs

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ay3fzw?file=index.tsx)

It's a simple react page with a header, nav and text content.

I'm trying to show the nav and then have it fixed at the top od the page when the page scrolls past the red header.

So I don't want it to showe when the page loads put then display it when the page scrolls past the res header.

I'm trying to use useEffect but I need to get a boolean some how to wrap the `<Nav />`

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0)
const [sticky, setSticky] = useState(false)

const handleScroll = () => {
  const position = window.pageYOffset
  setScrollPosition(position)
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, { passive: true })

  scrollPosition > 20 ? 'navShow' : 'navHide'

  return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Store a boolean which indicates whether the navbar should be shown or not and put it in your `useEffect` dependencies array.  And check if you should show the navbar... .

Comment: I thought thats what I trying to do here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bztybg?file=index.tsx

Comment: Yes u were on the right track, I meant you do not need to store the scroll position in the state. It probably causes your components to rerender every time user scrolls. Hope this helps https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ufyytv?file=Nav.tsx

Comment: Also not rendering the navbar causes your content to jump, you can hide it by CSS instead or wrap it around a div which has a fixed height.